# Understanding split() function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this code return 3 strings in the resulting list?

```python
def cat_dog(characters):
    n1 = characters.split('cat')
    print(n1)
    return len(n1)
```

On executing the code, I get the following. Why do I have 3 strings in my list? I'm trying to understanding how the `split()` method works. I would expect to see just 2 strings since I'm splitting at `cat` for the string `catcat` -- not sure why there are 3 strings in my new list after splitting.

```
cat_dog('catcat')

['', '', '']

3
```

Comment: Two split points means three strings. Did some part of the documentation confuse you? If so, could you please discuss it?

Comment: An empty string before the first `cat`, an empty string between `cat` and `cat`, an empty string after the last `cat`. Total of 3 empty strings. Sounds silly _for this example_ but that's how it works.

Comment: I tried this and got just 2 strings:

cat_dog('catdog')

['', 'dog']
2

why do I get 3 strings for repeated strings like 'catcat' but not for 'catdog'?

Comment: Because... there is only one `cat` in `catdog` but two in `catcat`? Think of it this way: Replace every `cat` with a comma (`,`) and you will see how it works. The first one becomes `,,` and the second one becomes `,dog`.

Comment: Actually I get it now. Thanks Selcuk

Answer (score 3):

According to [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split):

> `string.split(s[, sep[, maxsplit]])`: If the second argument *sep* is present and not `None`, it specifies a string to be used as the word separator.

So `characters.split('cat')` will return an array where the string is separated by the word `cat`. if you will call `"1cat2cat3".split('cat')`, you will get `["1", "2", "3"]`.

In your case, the string `catcat` can be represented as `'' + 'cat' + '' + 'cat' + ''`, so `'catcat'.split('cat')`
will return `['', '', '']`.

Answer (score 1):

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) should answer your question:

Quoted here:

> ...delimiters... are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')` returns `['1', '', '2']`).

In your case, the string `catcat` is treated as:

`'<empty_str>cat<empty_str>cat<empty_str>'` with `cat` as delimiter.